# PageViewer web part - busy indicator using jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have MySites displaying through an iFrame via the PageViewer Web part which takes some time to load initially. The user is unaware of content loading as it only shows a blank page until finished. Just wondering if anyone has a solution for showing a busy indicator or the SP 'Working on it' dialog until the load is finished.

I already have the following attached to the iFrame element (which hides some divs after it loads).

```
mySiteIframe.load(function(){
 //hide some divs
});
```

Is there a preload event I can use to display a busy indicator and hide it on the .load below? Or is there something OOB I can use? Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. It will show the SP Waiting dialog initially then hide it after the iFrame loads. Just throw this in a Content Editor with a script tag:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Show wait dialog initially
window.parent.eval("window.waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Loading MySites', '', 90, 450);");


var mySiteIframe = $("#MSOPageViewerWebPart_WebPartWPQ2");
   mySiteIframe.load(function(){

     //Close Wait Dialog after iFrame loads
     if (window.parent.waitDialog != null) 
     {
        window.parent.waitDialog.close();
     }

  });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Displaying a loading indicator on a iframe is quite easy. Just display the loading animation by default over the iframe and hide it when the javascript onload event for the iframe fires - like `onload="hideLoading()"`. In SP there are several ways to do this. You could edit the masterpage and insert the indicator hard, you could build your own pageviewer webpart that renders out a indicator, or you could do it fully client side.

The best way depends on your usecase.

[Here's some info about displaying and hiding the indicator.](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2010/07/13/display-animated-gif-before-iframe-content-is-loaded.aspx)

### Edit

[I actually created a very generic approach to do this.](http://liveweave.com/MGv3JH)

Comment: Thanks Max. This post didn't directly answer my question as  and I can't hard code the onload event in an iFrame that doesn't exist until the Pageviewer renders it.

Comment: You dont have to hardcode it. Attach it clientside via JS